# Child layout is out of bounds of the parent circle shape layout ANDROID

Tags: android, xml, layout, geometry, shapes

What i have now

[image: NOW]

What i want to achieve

[image]

My XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#BB69FF"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


My shape:

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="@color/restaurant_color" />

</shape>
```

What do you think? Do you have any suggestions? 
I tried to use android:clipChildren on the parent layout, but the result is the same.

Comment: May need a custom view for that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Relative parent layout, i am using this custom view-group 
https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout/blob/master/src/ru/biovamp/widget/CircleLayout.java and it looks fine.